# missing icon on alt-tab list Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: icons

Anyone updated to 14.04 and found missing icon while change to another window using alt-tab shortcut? attached is mine, and any solution for this problem is highly appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple, no need to reset unity icon. Just drag and drop your apps icon from unity dash to the launcher. Next time you open the application (for example terminal), the icon will be recognized by unity launcher.